# Get and modify yaml file from OpenShift API of the persisten volume in golang

Tags: api, go, kubernetes, openshift

I am trying to modify the `yaml` file of a `persistent volume` in `OpenShift` through the API in `Go(lang)`, I have the following

```
    pv, err := clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})


    for _, persV := range pv.Items {
        // Check status persistent volume
        pvStatus, err := clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().Get(persV.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        patch := []byte(`{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"containers":[{"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy":"Retain"}]}}}}`)
        a := fmt.Sprintf("%s", patch)
        fmt.Println(a)
        _, err = clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().Patch(persV.Name, types.StrategicMergePatchType, patch)
}
```

my `persistent volume` `yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
...
...
...
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
status:
  phase: Released
```

How could I get the `yaml` file and modify it from my actual `pvStatus`?
I would like to change `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain` to `persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete`

Answer (score 2):

Basically my error was constructing the `patch` `[]byte` value, the script should look like

```
 pv, err := clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().List(metav1.ListOptions{})


    for _, persV := range pv.Items {
        // Check status persistent volume
        pvStatus, err := clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().Get(persV.Name, metav1.GetOptions{})
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        patch := []byte(`{"spec": {"persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy": "Delete"}}`)
        _, err = clientset.CoreV1().PersistentVolumes().Patch(persV.Name, types.StrategicMergePatchType, patch)
```